# Update an array object from an another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

```
 $scope.Array1= [{
      Name: 'Alzheimers',
      Value: 1,
      Selected: false
  }, {
      Name: 'Arthritis',
      Value: 2,
      Selected: false
  },{
      Name: 'Cancer',
      Value: 3,
      Selected: false
  }{
      Name: 'Cellulitis',
      Value: 4,
      Selected: false
  }
  ];

$scope.Array2=[1,3];
```

I want the result like

```
$scope.Array1= [{
          Name: 'Alzheimers',
          Value: 1,
          Selected: true
      }, {
          Name: 'Arthritis',
          Value: 2,
          Selected: false
      },{
          Name: 'Cancer',
          Value: 3,
          Selected: true
      }{
          Name: 'Cellulitis',
          Value: 4,
          Selected: false
      }
      ];
```

the `selected` object variable`(Alzheimers,Cancer)` is updated to true from the `Array2`? **If you give the suggestion without  loop, then it would be great for me.**

Comment: `$scope.Array1.forEach(x => x.Selected = ($scope.Array2.indexOf(x.Value) != -1));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate `array1` with [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), check if the `Value` is included in `Array2`, and assign the result to the `Selected` property. This solution will mutate the original objects.

```js
const array1 = [{"Name":"Alzheimers","Value":1,"Selected":false},{"Name":"Arthritis","Value":2,"Selected":false},{"Name":"Cancer","Value":3,"Selected":false},{"Name":"Cellulitis","Value":4,"Selected":false}];

const array2 = [1, 3];

array1.forEach((o) => o.Selected = array2.includes(o.Value));

console.log(array1);
```

If you want a new array with the new objects, use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), with Object#assign.

```js
let array1 = [{"Name":"Alzheimers","Value":1,"Selected":false},{"Name":"Arthritis","Value":2,"Selected":false},{"Name":"Cancer","Value":3,"Selected":false},{"Name":"Cellulitis","Value":4,"Selected":false}];

const array2 = [1, 3];

array1 = array1.map((o) => array2.includes(o.Value) ? Object.assign({}, o, {
  Selected: true
}) : o);

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `forEach`

```js
let array1 = 
[
 {"Name":"Alzheimers","Value":1,"Selected":false},
 {"Name":"Arthritis","Value":2,"Selected":true},
 {"Name":"Cancer","Value":3,"Selected":false},
 {"Name":"Cellulitis","Value":4,"Selected":false}
];
let array2 = [1, 3];
array1.forEach(x => x.Selected = array2.indexOf(x.Value) != -1);
console.log(array1);
```